# Unable to track mistake for Eclipse plugin for context menu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When I am running my project as an Eclipse plugin project it is working fine. But when I am exporting it as Eclipse plugin and copied it into Eclipse plugins folder. After restarting eclipse, The context menu is not appearing...

The config defined for context menu in plugin.xml :

```
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
        <menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
            <command commandId="patch.easy" label="Add to Patch" style="push">
            </command>
        </menuContribution>
    </extension>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
        <command defaultHandler="com.createMenu.PatchMenu" id="patch.easy"
            name="Convert"></command>
    </extension>
```

Please help...

Comment: Some of your tags are not properly closed. I don't know if it due to copy-paste or if it's the problem you are actually facing.

Anyhow, try to properly indent your code for better readability.

Comment: Need more information... Put some logger to debug....

Comment: Sashi: First read the posted one properly